# C program and subprocess

Tags: python, c, subprocess

I wrote this simple C program to explain a more hard problem with the same characteristics.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int n;
    while (1){
        scanf("%d", &n);
        printf("%d\n", n);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

and it works as expected.

I also wrote a subprocess script to interact with this program:

```py
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT

process = Popen("./a.out", stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)

# sending a byte
process.stdin.write(b'3')
process.stdin.flush()

# reading the echo of the number
print(process.stdout.readline())

process.stdin.close()
```

The problem is that, if I run my python script, the execution is freezed on the `readline()`. In fact, if I interrupt the script I get:

```
/tmp » python script.py
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/script.py", line 10, in <module>
    print(process.stdout.readline())
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
KeyboardInterrupt
```

If I change my python script in:

```py
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT

process = Popen("./a.out", stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)

with process.stdin as pipe:
    pipe.write(b"3")
    pipe.flush()

# reading the echo of the number
print(process.stdout.readline())

# sending another num:
pipe.write(b"4")
pipe.flush()

process.stdin.close()
```

I got this output:

```
» python script.py
b'3\n'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/script.py", line 13, in <module>
    pipe.write(b"4")
ValueError: write to closed file
```

That means that the first input is sent correctly, and also the read was done.

I really can't find something that explain this behaviour; can someone help me understanding?
Thanks in advance

**[EDIT]**: since there are many points to clearify, I added this edit. I'm training on exploitation of buffer overflow vuln using the `rop` technique and I'm writing a python script to achieve that. To exploit this vuln, because of ASLR,  I need to discover the `libc` address and make the program restart without terminating. Since the script will be executed on a target machine, I dont know which libraries will be avaiable, then I'm going to use subprocess because it's built-in in python. Without going into details, the attack send a sequence of **bytes** on the first `scanf` aim to leak `libc` base address and restart the program; then a second payload is sent to obtain a shell with which I will communicate in interactive mode.

That's why:

1. I can only use built-in libraries
2. I have to send bytes and cannot append ending `\n`: my payload would not be aligned or may leeds to fails
3. I need to keep open the `stdin` open
4. I cannot change the C-code

Comment: Because your C program is not run in a terminal, it is running in block mode where some fixed number of bytes need to be written to stdout before it is actually flushed to the operating system and the parent program. You could try adding a flush to the c program after the print. And if you are on a linux-like system, running via pty or pexpect will emulate a terminal and get it working.

Comment: what if I'm not able to edit and compile again the C code?? Is there a way to do that? I know there are other python libraries which do it good, but I was trying not to use them...

Comment: Use the `pexpect` library. It runs the subprocess in a pty so its output will not be buffered.

Comment: The `process.stdin` stream seems to be getting closed at the end of the `with process.stdin as pipe:` block (as can be seen using the "strace" utility). Is that a feature of Python?

Comment: It does indeed seem to be a feature of using `with` on a stream. See https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/with-statement-in-python/

Comment: If this worked the way you expected and didn't close stdin early, how is `scanf` supposed to know that `3` is the entire number and that there aren't more digits coming later?

Comment: with "and it works as expected." I meant that the program C is continuously reading a number and echoing it. Sorry if I didn't get your point

Comment: So if you send byte `'3'` and then byte `'4'`, should your program read the number `34`? Why or why not?

Comment: I expected that, in python script, when i write `process.stdin.write(b'3'); process.stdin.flush()`, then byte 3 is caught by the C exe and does the echo. This echo should be red in python by the following `process.stdout.readline()`. After that, I want to be able to send another byte and read the echo, and so on... Briefly: send a payload, read the same payload, send another payload, read the second payload...

Comment: Don't you need a carriage return after the the number to be input

Comment: Well then you need to adjust your expectations, because `%d` doesn't scan individual bytes. It scans numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change these:

- Send a separator between the numbers read by the C program. scanf(3) accepts any non-digit byte as separator. For easiest buffering, send a newline (e.g. `.write(b'42\n')`) from Python. Without a separator, scanf(3) will wait for more digits indefinitely.
- After each write (both in C and Python), flush the output.

This works for me:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int n;
    while (1){
        scanf("%d", &n);
        printf("%d\n", n);
        fflush(stdout);  /* I've added this line only. */
    }
    return 0;
}
```

```
import subprocess

p = subprocess.Popen(
    ('./a.out',), stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
try:
  print('A'); p.stdin.write(b'42 '); p.stdin.flush()
  print('B'); print(repr(p.stdout.readline()));
  print('C'); p.stdin.write(b'43\n'); p.stdin.flush()
  print('D'); print(repr(p.stdout.readline()));
finally:
  print('E'); print(p.kill())
```

The reason why your original C program works when run interactively within the terminal window is that in C the output is automatically flushed when a newline (`\n`) is written to the terminal. Thus `printf("%d\n", n);` does an implicit `fflush(stdout);` in the end.

The reason why your original C program doesn't work when run from Python with `subprocess` is that it writes its output to a pipe (rather than to a terminal), and there is no autoflush to a pipe. What happens is that the Python program is waiting for bytes, and the C program doesn't write those bytes to the pipe, but it is waiting for more bytes (in the next `scanf`), so both programs are waiting for the other indefinitely. (However, there would be a partial autoflush after a few KiB (typically 8192 bytes) of output. But a single decimal number is too short to trigger that.)

If it's not possible to change the C program, then you should use a terminal device instead of a pipe for communication between the C and the Python program. The `pty` Python module can create the terminal device, this works for me with your original C program:

```
import os, pty, subprocess

master_fd, slave_fd = pty.openpty()
p = subprocess.Popen(
    ('./a.out',), stdin=slave_fd, stdout=slave_fd,
    preexec_fn=lambda: os.close(master_fd))
try:
  os.close(slave_fd)
  master = os.fdopen(master_fd, 'rb+', buffering=0)
  print('A'); master.write(b'42\n'); master.flush()
  print('B'); print(repr(master.readline()));
  print('C'); master.write(b'43\n'); master.flush()
  print('D'); print(repr(master.readline()));
finally:
  print('E'); print(p.kill())
```

If you don't want to send newlines from Python, here is a solution without them, it works for me:

```
import os, pty, subprocess, termios

master_fd, slave_fd = pty.openpty()
ts = termios.tcgetattr(master_fd)
ts[3] &= ~(termios.ICANON | termios.ECHO)
termios.tcsetattr(master_fd, termios.TCSANOW, ts)
p = subprocess.Popen(
    ('./a.out',), stdin=slave_fd, stdout=slave_fd,
    preexec_fn=lambda: os.close(master_fd))
try:
  os.close(slave_fd)
  master = os.fdopen(master_fd, 'rb+', buffering=0)
  print('A'); master.write(b'42 '); master.flush()
  print('B'); print(repr(master.readline()));
  print('C'); master.write(b'43\t'); master.flush()
  print('D'); print(repr(master.readline()));
finally:
  print('E'); print(p.kill())
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I cannot change the C-code. I just add it an edit; I said it in a comment and I forgot to add it. Sorry

Comment: I've added a Python program which works with the C code in your question unchanged.

Comment: I will try this script on the real program, because your solution include a trailing `\n`. I'm not sure it will work. Thanks for that

Comment: You need some separator between the two numbers 42 and 43, otherwise the C program would detect the number 4243.

Comment: I've added a Python program which doesn't send newlines to my answer.

Comment: I tried your code and I got an error after sending payload and read the next line. The concept is that: C program does a `printf`, wait for user input, and then another `scanf`. With the scanf data, i have to make another print using buff overflow. but This new line is never red and an error occurs: `OSError: [Errno 5] Input/output error`. I dont know, maybe i should post the original code even if it's not so easy to explain all the steps.

Comment: My code works for me with the C program in the question. You should accept this answer, and ask another question with a different C program. I think it's not fair for you to change the question as soon as I solve it, multiple times.

Answer (score 3):

> I really can't find something that explain this behaviour; can someone help me understanding?

There are at least two issues here:

1. **the C program's standard output is to a non-interactive device** (a pipe) and therefore the output is fully buffered.  The output will be accumulated in memory, only being sent to the output device when (i) the buffer fills, or (ii) it is manually flushed, or (iii) the program terminates normally.
2. **the C program runs indefinitely, with no way to make it terminate normally**.  Not even end-of-file on its standard input will make it stop.

On the Python side, then, the script is waiting for the subprocess's output to be flushed, whereas the subprocess needs to read and echo more data (probably a lot of it) before that will happen.  This is a deadlock.

Your best approach depends on how well the example C program models the behavior of the one in which you're really interested.

- **If it's faithful in every relevant detail**, then the only thing you can reasonably do is keep writing to the subprocess's `stdin` until something pops out on its `stdout`.  You probably want to do the data pushing in a separate thread, to avoid reproducing exactly the same kind of deadlock you already saw.
- **If it recognizes some kind of clean termination signal**, such as a "quit" command or EOF on its standard input, then have the Python side send that signal before trying to read the output.  Indeed, you already close `stdin`, so perhaps you don't actually need to do anything to accommodate the real program.

Note well that the first alternative leaves the subprocess running.  You will want to ensure that it terminates.  By `terminate()`ing or `kill()`ing it, if that's what it takes.

Comment: In the modified Python script, the "write" end of the pipe (`process.stdin` in the Python program) is automatically closed at the end of the `with` block, so that explains why the C program's `scanf()` function returns in that case (it will read EOF).

Comment: Thank you, @IanAbbott, I overlooked that.  I have updated this answer appropriately.  It turns out that removing the incorrect commentary was pretty clean.

Comment: Thanks for answer and explaination. Reading the [subprocess Popen doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) I found that `Popen` accepts a param `bufsize`. Using `bufsize = 0` "means unbuffered (read and write are one system call and can return short)". But if I add this value on `Popen` call, it seems to have no effect: the script behaves as before. Am I missing something??

Comment: @ma4strong "Am I missing something" You are. The buffering settings apply to your Python program, not to the subprocess it runs.

Answer (score -1):

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT

process = Popen("./a.out", stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT, text=True)

# sending a string with newline
process.stdin.write('3\n')
process.stdin.flush()

# reading the echo of the number
print(process.stdout.readline(), end='')

# sending another string with newline
process.stdin.write('4\n')
process.stdin.flush()

process.stdin.close()
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).